# Error getting values from row on 'delete' clicked in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am getting this error while I click on the delete button

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

And the GridView3_RowDeleting is as follows

```
protected void GridView3_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = GridView3.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
}
```

How can I access values of that particular row?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="16px" Height="5px" PageSize="5" OnRowDeleting="GridView3_RowDeleting" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView3_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DName" HeaderText="DName" SortExpression="DName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="bloodGroup" HeaderText="Group" SortExpression="bloodGroup" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="contact_number" HeaderText="Contact#" SortExpression="contact_number" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="dateDonated" HeaderText="dateDonated" SortExpression="dateDonated" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="city" SortExpression="city" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="arid_number" HeaderText="Arid#" SortExpression="arid_number" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I am not to familiar with them, but do the `GridViewDeleteEventArgs` have the values that you need in them?

Comment: I am not an ASP.NET c# expert. I want get values of that row where 'delete' button is clicked.

Comment: You have a delete button on each row? what does your markup look like?

Comment: please share your gridView markup

Comment: It is a 'CommandField'

Comment: @SiddiqueMahsud  
pastebin.com/7DRmPmcD

Comment: @user3110335 which value you want to access or are you trying to delete the row

Comment: @meda The row on where the delete is clicked.
Delete is actually 'CommandField'

Answer (score 0):

you are missing **DataKeyNames ** attribute in Gridview.

```
<asp:GridView DataKeyNames ="yourID"---------------------------------------->
```

if you use "DName" as your DataKeyNames like `<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="DName"` then you get column DName value of your deleting row in label

```
Label1.Text = GridView3.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

Label1.Text=(value of DName of your row thats deleting)

Following is a working example: May helpful

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductDesc" HeaderText="ProductDesc" SortExpression="ProductDesc" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthWindConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [ProductDesc] FROM [Product]" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Product] WHERE [ProductID] = @ProductID" >  
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>        
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here ProductID is uniqueKey using in DataKeyNames and in Deleting a record, while in your case DID...

---

Following should be your code...Enjoy

```
<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="DID" ID="GridView3" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="16px" 
Height="5px" PageSize="5" OnRowDeleting="GridView3_RowDeleting" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView3_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DID" HeaderText="DID" SortExpression="DID" Visible="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DName" HeaderText="DName" SortExpression="DName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="bloodGroup" HeaderText="Group" SortExpression="bloodGroup" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="contact_number" HeaderText="Contact#" SortExpression="contact_number" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="dateDonated" HeaderText="dateDonated" SortExpression="dateDonated" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="city" SortExpression="city" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="arid_number" HeaderText="Arid#" SortExpression="arid_number" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tblDonors] WHERE [DID]=@DID" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [DName], [gender], [bloodGroup], [contact_number], [city], [arid_number], [avallibilityTime], [dateDonated], [email] FROM [tblDonors]">
    <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="DID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>  
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: yourID ?

Sorry for my limited knowledge

Comment: use "DName" or any other column name in place of yourID.

Comment: sorry brother it not DataKeys but DataKeyNames in gridView markup, i edited my answer

Comment: Now getting error
Deleting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless DeleteCommand is specified.
Even I have specified.
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Test.dbo.tblUser] WHERE [DID]=81"

Comment: Also share your datasource

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Test.dbo.tblUser WHERE [DID]=76" SelectCommand="SELECT [DName], [gender], [bloodGroup], [contact_number], [city], [arid_number], [avallibilityTime], [dateDonated], [email] FROM [tblDonors]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: I edit my question, please you should add DID column to your gv and also use as you DataKeyNames and use in where clause in deletCommand. Like DID=@DID, also create parameter for DID and in my example ProductID